# Cron job with node-cron will not console.log for a test

Tags: node.js, express, cron, node-cron

I am trying to run a test cron job in my node.js app (one just for this job) but it is not `console.log()` like it should be. It should `console.log()` every 10 seconds but it won't.

This is my only file in my directory/app other than package.json file and node_modules directory.

The code is here:

```
var express     = require("express"),
    app         = express(),
    bodyParser  = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose    = require("mongoose"),
    cron = require("node-cron");


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/asset-management-v1");
// mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/yelp_camp_v10");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));


app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
   next();
});

var task = cron.schedule('10 * * * *', function() {
  console.log('immediately started');
}, false);

task.start();
```

My end goal is to check a `mongodb collection` then look at the `objectID` of each and if the `objectID` time stamp is older than 10 days to send out an email using `nodemailer`. If you see anything other than the thing causing the `console.log` to fail please point it out so I don't have to come back and bother you all more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10 * * * *` - means "every 10 minutes". You need `10 * * * * *` to run it every 10 seconds.

And you can pass `true` to start it immediately:

```
var task = cron.schedule('10 * * * *', function() {
  console.log('immediately started');
}, true);
```